# Why can NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM create SQL Server database backups?

Tags: sql-server, backup, permissions, database-backup

I have a scheduled task (in Windows Task Scheduler) that connects to SQL Server using SMO (Windows Authentication) and creates a database backup. So far, this task was running under the Administrator account and I wanted to change it to use the SYSTEM account instead.

I changed the scheduled task and, to my utter surprise, it worked out-of-the-box.

I'd like to understand *why* this is the case. The system is Windows Server 2012 R2, and the database is SQL Server 2012 (SP1) Express Edition. It's a standard installation with one SQL Auth user added.

In SSMS, these are the logins and their associated server roles:

- ##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin## *(disabled)*
- ##MS_PolicyTsqlExecutionLogin## *(disabled)*
- MyServer\Administrator (public, sysadmin)
- MySqlAuthUser (public)
- BUILTIN\Users (public)
- NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (public)
- NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER (public, sysadmin)
- NT SERVICE\SQLWriter (public, sysadmin)
- NT SERVICE\Winmgmt (public, sysadmin)
- sa (public, sysadmin)

The database itself has the following users and their roles:

- MySqlAuthUser (Login MySqlAuthUser) (db_owner)
- dbo (Login sa) (db_owner)
- guest *(disabled)*
- INFORMATION_SCHEMA *(disabled)*
- sys *(disabled)*

Viewing the "effective permissions" of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM yields the following output:

- ALTER ANY AVAILABILITY GROUP
- CONNECT SQL
- CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP
- VIEW ANY DATABASE
- VIEW SERVER STATE

Why does NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM have permission to backup databases? I'm glad that it does, but I'd really like to understand *why*...

Answer (score 11):

The minimum permissions to back up a database are `PUBLIC` at the server level and `DB_BACKUPOPERATOR` at a database level.

In SQL Server 2005, Microsoft [recommended against](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919023) removing `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` from the sysadmin role:

> The NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account is also granted a SQL Server login.
>   The NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account is provisioned in the SYSADMIN fixed
>   server role. Do not delete this account or remove it from the SYSADMIN
>   fixed server role. The NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account is used by Microsoft
>   Update and by Microsoft SMS to apply service packs and hotfixes to a
>   SQL Server 2005 installation. The NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account is also
>   used by the SQL Writer Service.

[This is no longer the case in 2012.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500459.aspx)  I double-checked on my own instance of 2012 Express:  `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` is not a sysadmin.  However, the `SQL Service VSS Writer` *is* running as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` and *is* a sysadmin.

I'm not able to find any links backing up that this is why `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` is allowed to back up databases, but I believe that's the case.